# Is this sentence with "dürfen" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to say "**You probably called me in the morning**" but using "dürfen".

Is it just "**Du darfst mich am Morgen angerufen haben**"?

Also, maybe some comments on how to use it?

Comment: Which dictionary entry for *dürfen* has lead you to assume that your sentence conveys the desired meaning?

Comment: Das dürfte "du dürftest mich heute Morgen angerufen haben" sein.

Comment: @tofro Dein Kommentar dürfte ein Fall für "Please don't answer in comments" sein - aber das dürftest Du wohl besser wissen :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz Mein Kommentar dürfte dürfte eher so zu verstehen sein, dass er ein Hinweis an Closevoter sein dürfte, dass "unclear what you're asking" hier kein Close-Grund sein dürfte.

Comment: @tofro Diese (versteckte) Botschaft dürfte ich dann wohl nicht mitbekommen haben :)

Comment: Weder das -1 noch das Close-Vote ist von mir, aber dass man raten kann, was gemeint ist, heißt nicht, dass die Frage nicht unklar ist.

Comment: @carsten_s he probably looked up "may" and saw, among other words, vielleicht (May=might=probably) and dürfen (May=are allowed to).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably referring to the meaning of *dürfen* that is listed in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/duerfen) under 1.e.

> es ist wahrscheinlich, dass …

Your example sentence would be written as:

> Du dürftest mich am Morgen angerufen haben.

To construct sentences that way, you use the *Konjuktiv II* of dürfen (see the [canoo table](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/d%C3%BCrfen:V:haben))

Answer (score 3):

Leider muss ich auf Deutsch antworten. Das folgende soll keine 'letzte Wahrheit' sein, sondern ein Diskussionsbeitrag. Der Grund ist, dass ich den vorgeschlagenen Satz für pragmatisch fehlerhaft halte. Er ist grammatisch nicht zu beanstanden, kann aber sozusagen nur unter Laborbedingungen erzeugt werden und funktioniert nicht oder nur mit abenteuerlichen zusätzlichen Annahmen in der sprachlichen Realität.

Der "epistemische" (Duden-Grammatik 2006 S. 563) bzw. "subjektive Gebrauch" der Modalverben (deutschegrammatik20.de) der Konjunktiv-II-Formen der Modalverben kennzeichnet, das ist richtig, verschiedene Grade an Wahrscheinlichkeit der getroffenen Aussagen, aber nicht nur. Ich kann das hier nur umreißen.

Nehmen wir als Beispiel den

> Satz A: Peter ist in Berlin angekommen.

Solange man dafür keine Bestätigung hat, können darüber nur Vermutungen angestellt werden.

> Er **müsste** inzwischen in Berlin angekommen sein.

Damit sagt der Sprecher, verkürzt gesagt, dass ihm nichts bekannt ist, weswegen Peter nicht inzwischen in Berlin angekommen sein sollte. Oder kürzer: Nach Adam Riese (und meinen Berechnungen) muss er jetzt eigentlich dort angekommen sein, aber mit absoluter Sicherheit kann man das natürlich nicht wissen, darum: müsste.

> Er **dürfte** inzwischen in Berlin angekommen sein.

Dies sagt aus, dass der Sprecher sich dazu berechtigt fühlt, davon auszugehen, dass Satz A gilt. Der dürfte-Satz erscheint mir subjektiver als der Satz mit *müsste* und betont die stärker Überzeugtheit des Sprechers als den logisch-objektiven Kontext der Aussage.

> Er **könnte** inzwischen in Berlin angekommen sein.

Dies bezeichnet es aus Sprechersicht als weniger wahrscheinlich, aber auch als nicht auszuschließen, dass Satz A erfüllt ist. Der Sprecher könnte auch sagen: Gut möglich, dass er schon da ist, aber das würde mich denn doch wundern.

> Er **sollte** inzwischen in Berlin angekommen sein.

Dies drückt vorrangig die Erwartung des Sprechers aus, dass Satz A erfüllt ist.

> Er **wird** inzwischen in Berlin angekommen sein.

Dies ist eine neutrale Vermutung, ohne Wahrscheinlichkeitseinstufung und ohne Überzeugtheits- oder Nicht-Überzeugtheitsanteil des Sprechers von der Erfülltheit der Aussage.

Man kann auch die nicht-konjunktivischen Formen der Modalverben (muss, kann, mag, soll) einsetzen, das führt hier zu weit.

Es macht unter normalen Umständen wenig Sinn, einer angesprochenen Person gegenüber Vermutungen darüber anzustellen, was sie möglicherweise getan hat, noch dazu wenn dieses Tun auf einen selbst bezogen ist, außer wenn der Sprecher zu einer Person spricht, die schwere Gedächtnisprobleme hat und sich nicht mehr an das erinnert, was sie am Morgen getan hat.

Damit so ein Satz unter gesunden Menschen geäußert werden könnte, müssten z.B. folgende Bedingungen erfüllt sein:

1. Der Sprecher hat am Morgen keinen Anruf des Angesprochenen
   angenommen.
2. Wenn der Sprecher ehrlich ist, weiß er nicht, ob der andere
   versucht hatte, ihn telefonisch zu erreichen.
3. Der Sprecher misstraut dem Angesprochenen, sonst würde er ihn direkt fragen: 
   "*Hast du mich nicht am Morgen angerufen?*".
4. Es muss einen Grund geben, warum der Sprecher diesen Satz sagt. 
   Ein solcher Grund ist sehr schwer zu finden, etwa:
5. Vorheriger Satz des Angesprochenen: *Ich hatte zig Mal versucht, dich zu erreichen, aber du bist ja nicht ans Telefon gegangen.* - Du dürftest mich am Morgen angerufen haben, da bin ich aber immer auf dem Golfplatz und habe das Telefon ausgeschaltet. Es wäre ausgesprochen ungalant, wenn ich dort anfange, wie ein Teenager zu telefonieren."

In diesem Fall würde die Antwort eher lauten:

> Du wirst mich (wohl) am Vormittag angerufen haben.

oder noch 'natürlicher'

> Na dann hast du mich wohl immer am Vormittag angerufen, aber da war ich ...

Es könnte auch sein, dass der Sprecher

6. ein Selbstgespräch führt, bei dem der andere anwesend ist, oder dass er
7. im stummen Selbstgespräch einen Dialog mit dem anderen simuliert.

Wenn der Sprecher nicht ehrlich ist, gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten:

8. Er weiß, dass der andere ihn angerufen hatte. Oder:
9. Er weiß, dass der andere ihn nicht angerufen hatte.

Situationen, in denen eine der Bedingungen 6 bis 9 erfüllt ist, sind möglicherweise nicht auszuschließen, aber sie sind voraussichtlich nur unter derart konstruierten Bedingungen vorstellbar, dass die Äußerung des Satzes mit '*dürftest*' so oder so an den Haaren herbeigezogen wirkt.

Als Grund dafür sehe ich, dass dieses "epistemische" *dürfte* über die reine Wahrscheinlichkeit hinaus eben auch die (schwache, aber vorhandene) **Überzeugtheit** des Sprechers davon zum Ausdruck bringt, dass das im Satz genannte Ereignis stattgefunden hat. Eine solche Überzeugtheit zu äußern, macht nur gegenüber einem Dritten Sinn, der daran zweifeln könnte. Der Satz würde daher in der dritten Person funktionieren:

> Er dürfte mich am Morgen angerufen haben.

Ob in solchen Fällen nicht die 'reine Vermutung' mit Futur II bevorzugt würde

> Er wird mich am Morgen angerufen haben

kann hier erst einmal offen bleiben.

[Ich vermute, das muss alles noch einmal in der 2. Person untersucht werden, denn es lassen sich Sätze finden, in denen "du dürftest * haben" soviel bedeutet wie *du wirst vermutlich * haben". Mal sehen, wann ich Zeit dafür habe.]

Comment: Das ist eigentlich keine Antwort. Auf der anderen Seite: Sprache und die Menschen, die sie nutzen, sind nicht immer so logisch, wie du das gerne zu haben scheinst.

Comment: @tofro: Nun, dann gebe ich mal eine Antwort, und zwar ganz direkt: Der Satz ist komplett unsinnig. Es ist ein typischer Satz, wie man ihn sich ausdenken kann, um zu demonstrieren, was man mit der deutschen Sprache rein grammatikalisch alles veranstalten kann, wenn einem der Inhalt völlig egal ist. Ich unterrichte Deutsch, ich arbeite nie mit Sätzen, die kein Deutscher sagen würde und hielte das auch für keine empfehlenswerte Methode. Auch unterschätzt Du die Menschen: Außer in der Psychiatrie oder Dichtkunst wirst Du kaum jemanden finden, der diesen Satz spontan sagen würde.

Comment: Deinen Punkt (5) halte ich für eine vollwertige Erklärung und den Satz für einen Satz, den man durchaus auch außerhalb psychatrischer Behandlung zu hören kriegen kann. Du begründest in keinster Weise, warum deine genannten Alternativen "besser" sein sollten.

Comment: @tofro: Da der Satz für Dich völlig normal zu sein scheint, wird es Dir ein Leichtes sein, auch mal selbst einen Kontext zu finden, in dem er vorkommen kann. Dann mal ran! Außerdem: Wenn wir uns noch einmal die Ausgangsfrage anschauen: Würdest Du dem Fragesteller empfehlen, sich so auszudrücken? Du sprichst von meinen "Alternativen": Wovon sprichst du da? Der Satz ist unheilbar. Fehlende Begründungen: Noch nicht lang genug? Vielleicht belassen wir es dabei, dass Du den Satz prima findest. Ich empfehle meinen Deutschlernern, sich normal auszudrücken, Deutsch ist auch so schon schwer genug.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Inhaltlich finde ich deine Antwort gut. ABER: wenn du deinen Deutschlernern empfiehlst, sich normal auszudrücken, warum benutzt du dann hier gegenüber einem Deutschlerner eine so gestelzte Sprache, dass du dich schließlich selbst darin verfängst? Der Satz *... dass er ... Grund hat, mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit davon auszugehen ...* ist (wie nennst du es so schön) *unheilbar*. Ist die Wahrscheinlichkeit hoch, dass er davon ausgeht, ...? Oder geht er davon aus, dass mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit ...? Noch einmal: deine Empfehlung finde ich sehr gut. Warum hältst du dich nicht dran?

Comment: @Olafant: Ja, mein Satz ist schrecklich. Er bezieht sich auf tofro, das ist also ein Kollegenstreit und keine Hilfestellung für blutige Anfänger, als solche wäre der von mir angezettelte Denkanstoß komplett ungeeignet. Ich finde es immer wenig hilfreich, wenn mit Retortensätzen argumentiert wird, und ich wollte zeigen, dass tofros aus dem Handgelenk geschüttelter korrigierter Satz in der Realität nicht funktionieren kann. Bei so einer 'Beweisführung' muss man sich in viele Richtungen absichern, kurz: Es sollte nicht schön werden (ist es auch nicht), sondern möglichst präzise. Kritik akzeptiert

Answer (score 0):

[DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) translates to "Du hast mich wahrscheinlich morgens angerufen."

I like this translation the best, it sounds most like German for everyday use.